# CSS Body Not Reaching to Page Borders

Tags: css

The content on my website isn't reaching all the way out to the page borders I've created, but there's no padding to it. How can I make it go out closer to the edges so everything isn't crammed in the center?

Here's my page for reference: https://jacobtrauberman.com/

Comment: your html has some margin, have you tried to remove it?

Comment: line no 403,  html { margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20% remove it

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: I didn't add any code because I couldn't find any in the Dev Tools that would cause the gap I mentioned. I'm sorry it was vague.

As far as the issue, it's not the margins that are my problem. It's the dark green gaps between the text and the border (and between text/sidebar on the right ride). I want to make that green gap a lot narrower, but I want to keep the black margins on the outsides the way they are.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are these rules for `<html>` tag

```
html {
    margin-left: 20%;
    border-style: double;
    border-color: #d1a657;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

you can play with **margin-left/right** and reduce the percentage to make the `<body>` taking more space in the page :)

hope this help

Comment: I actually set the margins on purpose. My problem is with the dark green gaps between the text and the border (and between text/sidebar on the right ride). I want to make that green gap a lot narrower, but I want to keep the black margins on the outsides the way they are.

Comment: in my browser i have these rules active, try to change that to do what you need.
`@media (min-width: 1250px) 
.site-main {
    margin: 0 6% 0 6%;
}
`
reduce the margin right and left for `.site-main` class

But keep attention of the other selector `@media (min-width: 850px) 
.site-main {
margin: 0 30% 0 0;
}
`